# Problem with ListBox on WP7 - System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, xamlparseexception

everyone.
I got a listBox. When I try to show 61 items - it runs OK.
But when it's 62 or more - apps falls with

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message= [Line: 0 Position: 0]
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

What can it be - I have no clue.. It falls out in a random moment. I can scroll listBox to end, see last element, and when I scroll back - it throw error.

Comment: How are you adding items to the listbox? Are you adding them in code or directly in the markup? If you're adding them in markup, can you post the markup for the last few items?

Comment: I add items in code. via ItemsSource property

Comment: You should be adding items to the `ObservableCollection<T>` that has been assigned to the `ItemsSource` property, not directly to the `ItemsSource` property itself.

Comment: Can you post some code (XAML and C#)?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have variable-height items in your listbox. You can try changing the the ListBox.ItemsPanel to be a StackPanel instead of the VirtualizingStackPanel. This will allow variable height items, but there is a tradeoff because if you have a lot of items in the list then you are going to increase startup time and memory usage.